The list of youtube videos by date is not effective
I'm running a piece of code to list the latest YouTube videos from my channel.
However, whether on this code or on the YouTube test platform, I do have the last 4 videos published, but the following ones are old videos, and not the ones that should be next.
Here is my code :
$video_list = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&type=video&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));

    $json = '[';
    
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($video_list->items as $item) {

        if($i > 0){ $json .= ','; }
        $json .= '
        {
            "videoId": "'. $item->id->videoId .'",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='. $item->id->videoId .'",
            "title": "'. $item->snippet->title .'",
            "description": "'. $item->snippet->description .'",
            "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'. $item->id->videoId .'/hqdefault.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "'. $item->snippet->publishedAt .'"
        }';
        $i++;

    } 
    $json .= ']';
    //echo fJson($json);
    file_put_contents('youtube.json', fJson($json));

And the result
[
  {
    "videoId": "fSvy6ZHM2vY",
    "title": "Terre de sports - le showdown un sport meéconnu destiné aux non voyants",
    "description": "Lointain cousin du tennis de table et du air hockey, le showdown est un sport étonnant qui commence à trouver de nombreux ...",
    "publishedAt": "2024-04-17T06:46:23Z"
  },
  {
    "videoId": "wgG-SaK3KyM",
    "title": "RECETTE GAGNANTE POUR LES BURGERS SOLIDAIRES DU DÉPARTEMENT",
    "description": "Lundi 15 avril, le Président de la Seine-Maritime, Bertrand Bellanger a officialisé la distribution de la recette de l'opération “burger ...",
    "publishedAt": "2024-04-17T06:35:55Z"
  },
  {
    "videoId": "kjzcF7hFTDE",
    "title": "Carnet d&#39;expos - La beauté cachée des graines",
    "description": "Elles sont symboles de vie, de croissance, de diversité et de culture aussi. Des graines de toutes sortes sont passées sous ...",
    "publishedAt": "2024-04-15T13:52:36Z"
  },
  {
    "videoId": "zGvn6VJWu5E",
    "title": "L&#39;abbaye Saint-Georges, une plongée dans des jardins monastiques",
    "description": "Ces jardins vivriers labellisés « jardin remarquable » avec leur potager, leurs plantes médicinales et leurs fruitiers ont été ...",
    "publishedAt": "2024-04-12T13:15:04Z"
  },
  {
    "videoId": "wrJAjhXGdAw",
    "title": "BOUJOU LA SEINE - Les insolites d&#39;Ariane Au Genetey, un manoir de légendes",
    "description": "Au Genetey, un manoir de légendes : C'est un lieu chargé d'histoires, blotti au fond d'une impasse, en lisière de forêt.",
    "publishedAt": "2023-07-15T06:00:18Z"
  },
  {
    "videoId": "KFoMkpi4KqA",
    "title": "BOUJOU LA SEINE - Les insolites d&#39;Ariane - la nature a trouvé son refuge",
    "description": "À Heurteauville, une ancienne tourbière cache un trésor de biodiversité. Le lieu, classé Espace Naturel Sensible est aujourd'hui ...",
    "publishedAt": "2023-07-08T06:00:12Z"
  },
...

The last 2 videos are not the ones I should have, I posted more in April 2024. What's the problem ?
Thank you

$json .=...no. Don't build JSON strings by hand. Build a PHP array and then json_encode it at the end, when you save it to the file. It's far less likely to go wrong due to syntax problems etc. That's not the root cause of the problem in your question, but it is something you ought to change

Using this approach solves your issue.

Désolé je n'ai pas compris... hormis qu'il faudrait passer par une playlist ? Le flux RSS YouTube me sort bien une liste correcte, mais ça me paraît moins propre en sortie, donc je voudrais utiliser l'API. Et je n'ai pas besoin de pagination

Sorry you must write everything in English here please - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions

First of all, DON'T construct JSON by hand! There's too much that could go wrong. You can pretty-print the JSON if you like, using json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
Second of all, use urlencode() to encode parameters because it's the safest. Always do it. If you have it installed, use a library like guzzle/psr7 to encode your URLs.
I added a custom sorting routine here using usort(). If you want to reverse them, use array_reverse($data) after sorting.
<?php

$video_list = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&type=video&part=snippet&channelId='.urlencode($channelID).'&maxResults='.urlencode($maxResults).'&key='.urlencode($API_key).''));

$data = [];

foreach ($video_list->items as $item) {
    $data[] = [
        'videoId' => $item->id->videoId,
        'url' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . urlencode($item->id->videoId),
        'title' => $item->snippet->title,
        'description' => $item->snippet->description,
        'thumbnail' => "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{$item->id->videoId}/hqdefault.jpg",
        'publishedAt' => $item->snippet->publishedAt,
    ];
}

// Sort videos by publishedAt, oldest toward beginning
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    $time_a = strtotime($a['publishedAt']);
    $time_b = strtotime($b['publishedAt']);
    if ($time_a > $time_b) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($time_b > $time_a) {
        return -1;
    }
    // $time_a == $time_b
    return 0;
});

// Encode json, with indenting
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

//echo fJson($json);
file_put_contents('youtube.json', fJson($json));

There are some curveballs here as there are any time you're dealing with dates; timestamps during the hour when we "fall back" during daylight savings are ambiguous, but you're probably not gonna care about that.

I am agree with you, but this doesn't solve the problem. The source is the same, I have the same videos in the array. I think it's a mistake on the query maybe ?
